# mysql YearWeek() doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all data from my database within a current week.. and if that week is already over I want the next week data to be shown without showing the last weeks data....

here's my code: I've tried using `YearWeek()`

```
            Select
                systemusers.FirstName,
                systemusers.MiddleName,
                systemusers.LastName, 
                temperaturelogs.DateTime,
                Locations.Description,
                temperaturelogs.UnitID,
                temperaturelogs.Temperature,
                temperaturelogs.Humidity
            From temperaturelogs 
            Inner Join Locations 
            On temperaturelogs.LocationID = Locations.LocationID
            Inner Join SystemUsers
            On temperaturelogs.Encoder = systemusers.UserID
            Where
            YEARWEEK('3/21/2016') = YEARWEEK(NOW())
            AND
            temperaturelogs.Encoder = 2 Order By temperaturelogs.DateTime DESC
```

Comment: Try `yearweek('2016-03-21')`.  The probably is probably the date format, not the function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is it possible for me to get all the data from march 20 - 26?  my result's not what I expected though.

Answer (score 0):

based on a week from Monday 12:00 AM to Sunday 11:59:59.999PM

```
Where YourColumn >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE() -1), 0)
```

Comment: but I am supplying the current date instead of week? is it okay?

Comment: it should be okay, try it and let me know if it works or not, in order to update my answer to settle your query :)

Comment: doesn't work though.... I happen to solve my problem...
`YEARWEEK(temperaturelogs.DateTime) = YEARWEEK(NOW())`